# Override externally defined type definition or function definition

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I am making a file sharing service.

I have a type called `ValidatedPath` which represents a string that has been processed through the validate() function, which checks that the string is a valid path.

```js
export type ValidatedPath = string & { __type: "ValidatedPath" };

function validate(path: string): ValidatedPath | null {
    // Severely shortened for clarity
    if(false === regex.test(path)) return null;
    return path as ValidatedPath;
}
```

The problem is, the ValidatedPath does not actually represent an actual path in the file system, only a path valid relative to a certain directory.

For example:

`folder/folder2/file` is a ValidatedPath, but the real path should be `/Users/hello/folder/folder2/file`, which I will obtain after a call through `path.join(baseDirectory, validatedPath)`

However, because ValidatedPath is a subtype of string, I am allowed to pass it into file system functions, which will result in errors as that is not correct behavior.

For example:

```js
async function rename(original: ValidatedPath, destination: ValidatedPath) {
    await fs.rename(original, destination); // This is allowed, but it's wrong!
    
    const realOriginal: string = path.join(baseDirectory, original);
    const realDestination: string = path.join(baseDirectory, destination);
    await fs.rename(realOriginal, realDestination); // This is correct!
}
```

### Solutions:

I have some solutions in mind, which I do not currently know how to implement, if they are even possible at all.

##### Solution 1:

The file system functions take in a type called `PathLike` as a parameter, defined in some node_modules file. Can I somehow override or modify this externally defined type `PathLike`?

```js
// Externally defined
type PathLike = string | Buffer | URL;
function rename(oldPath: PathLike, newPath: PathLike): Promise<void>;
```

##### Solution 2:

I can make it so that `ValidatedPath` is not a subset of string:

```js
export type ValidatedPath = Omit<string, "toLocaleString">;
```

This will make it so that it is no longer valid to pass in ValidatedPath into the file system functions. However, this will make it not work with `path.join()`, as it takes strings only. It's annoying to always write,

```js
const realPath = path.join(baseDirectory, validatedPath as string);
```

but it would be significantly less annoying if I can modify the single function path.join to take either string OR ValidatedPath, so that the type assertion is no longer necessary. Can I somehow override or modify this externally defined function definition `path.join`?

---

If none of the above is possible, it may just be that I am forced to use Solution 2 without overriding `path.join`, type asserting ValidatedPaths as strings every time I want to use a function that takes strings. It's annoying, but I can live with it. I just think that there must be a better solution out there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, first of fall, your code is missing some variables and imports; please include them or remove their usage.  Have you considered making a wrapper around the file system functions with restrictions to the type?

`const myRename = (oldName: NotValidatedPath, newName: notValidatedPath) => rename(oldName, newName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the use of casting muliple times bothers you, a wrapper function would be a solution. You could just create your own `pathJoin` function which accepts your `ValidatedPath` type and cast it into a string type or converts it to a string using `String` function and return the call of the path.join().

```
function pathJoin(val: ValidatedPath) {
    return path.join(val as string)
}
```